# Getting the [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALRTNAME_INVALID] error when trying to do POST request

Tags: node.js, ssl

Im trying to do a POST request towards a particular domain (ill refer to it as api.example.com/base) but i cannot pass the [conditional SSL certificate checking nodejs does in the tls module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/38c938aa90a4346f0fc4e2ec77ebf180386f9ee5/lib/tls.js#L164-L242). I can do the same POST request in Curl without problem, and i can do POST requests towards other domains in nodejs fine, but not for this particular domain (which again works fine in Curl).

**The POST request:**

```
function PostReq() {

    let chunks = [], resData = '';

    const postData = decodeURIComponent(qs.stringify({
        property1: 'value1',
        property2: 'value2'
    }));

    const options = {
        headers: {
            host: 'api.example.com',
            path: '/base',
            port: 443,
            method: 'POST',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData),
        }
    };


    const reqPost = https.request(options, (res) => {

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log('got successfull http response');

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                console.log('getting chunks...');
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                resData = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
                console.log('response body data: ', resData);
            });
        } else {
            console.error('received http status code: ', res.Statuscode);
        }
    });

    reqPost.write(postData);

    reqPost.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('error: ', err);
    });

    reqPost.end();
}
PostReq();
```

**Error message:**

```
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: api.example.com. is not in the cert's altnames: mydomain.com, DNS:www.mydomain.com
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:283:12)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1331:27)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12) {
  reason: "Host: api.example.com. is not in the cert's altnames: mydomain.com, DNS:www.mydomain.com"
```

**The stack:**

- nodejs
- expressjs
- nginx
- nginx reverse proxy
- letsencrypt ssl certificate

There are no errors in the nginx or letsencrypt log either so they are fine.

Ive tried setting the NPM configuration setting ssl-strict to false but it didnt help. There is an solution that probably works, which is setting the *rejectUnauthorized* value to *false* but this causes serios security issues which im trying to avoid so id be grateful if anyone knows what is going on here and how to fix it.

Comment: curl (unless you specify `-k/--insecure`) should make the same checks and also fail if it is getting the same cert -- but many servers today require SNI to return the correct cert and curl sends SNI automatically but nodejs.tls does not. Try adding `servername` per https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_port_host_options_callback . If you have `openssl` installed, `s_client` allows you to try _both_ ways and compare, but the details now vary with version making it too long for a comment; see the man page.

Comment: I do the curl request without the insecure parameter. I tried passing the servername to the options object parameter in the `https.request()` method but i still get the same error. Do you mean making an connection directly from `tls.connect()` instead of `https.request()`? And for the openssl part, you mean doing the command in the shell? Because i want the code to be only nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED.**

I did a pretty obvious mistake in my code above, i added all the options properties in the headers object.

What i did:

```
const options = {
    headers: {
        host: 'api.example.com',
        path: '/base',
        port: 443,
        method: 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData),
    }
};
```

What i should have done (the correct way):

```
const options = {
    host: 'api.example.com',
    path: '/base',
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
    }
};
```

So if you are getting this issue, double check your code formatting, sometimes the issue is just an simple flaw!